# How to get auto_id in Django Form's clean() method?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class AForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=(
            ('a', _('Some option')),
        ),
        widget=forms.Select()
    )

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        widget_id = # How do I get the auto generated id here?
```

I understand you can get `auto_id` in templates, but I'd like to include such information in our AJAX response.

Comment: As one option, id of fields use simple scheme: "id_" + field_name. In your example field id should be "id_field".

Comment: @demalexx That is true. :].  However, is my question feasible?  If there isn't a way to programatically get it, we'd have to write the id for every field manually.

Comment: Hang on, do you need it in `clean` or in the AJAX response? That's two different questions.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to have it in the AJAX response.  The `clean()` just happen to be one of the examples good for this question.  Is there another way you would advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at Django's forms code, and found that this should work:

```
class AForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        widget_id = self['field'].auto_id
```

The trick is we use `Form['field']`, that in turn calls `BaseForm.__getitem__` and it returns `BoundField` instance. `BoundField` has some interesting properties like `auto_id`. Looks like it respects form's `prefix` attribute.

I'm not sure whether it's ok to do this, I've done it for the first time, so I wouldn't recommend using it until you investigate that it's ok :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll give it a try and see what I can find.

Comment: I don't notice any side effects by accessing this attribute. Cheers!